# Advice on learning software development and design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

I've been programming for a while and I know basics of Java, C, and C++. I know a bit of Object Oriented Programming. At the moment, I'm trying to improve my knowledge (and I need to use C# for a programming project).

But I feel really lost and frustrated in this path. I want to learn more than just the basics of a language. I want to learn Design Patterns and developing and planning a software project but I don't know how to proceed.

I tried reading books on Design Patterns but they feel so abstract when I don't have a specific project to do. I'm really confused on this, how did you learn Object Oriented Design and Design Patterns? I feel that if I just read a book, I won't learn much.

I feel that Head First Design Patterns book tries to make it too simplistic. And the Gang of Four book feels too theoretical (and it says you need to learn Object Oriented Design first). I like books/resources that are more direct-to-the-point and have some exercises.

What would your suggestion be in this situation?

Comment: code up and step through as many of the patterns in the gof book.

Answer (score 0):

A middle road you may find of interest (between the abstract nature of the Gang of Four book, and simple Head First Design Patterns) - try:

Martin Fowler - Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (the book). You can see at preview of the pattern catalog at http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Also consider: Michael T. Nygard - Release It - contains some excellent patterns related to reliability, scalability, and similar concerns: http://pragprog.com/book/mnee/release-it

These books may be at a higher level (application architecture) than you are seeking, but provide very concrete problems and solutions.

Comment: fowler's poeaa is very good, but it is not about *design* patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read some great books that really explain what is going on. I'd go with [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and [Designing Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136298257). Those books won't teach you design patterns directly, but you'll learn how to create great design solutions for every problem you face. Design Patterns are precooked solutions for only a few cases. You need to be able to solve every possible problem on your own. After that, learning Design Patterns is a child's play...